# Iterate and map JSON dictionary to build array of objects - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I've got this response from JSOn web service:

```
categoria =     (
                {
            "id_categoria" = 61;
            imagen = "http://exular.es/mcommerce/image/data/ipod_classic_4.jpg";
            nombre = Gorras;
        },
                {
            "id_categoria" = 59;
            imagen = "http://exular.es/mcommerce/image/data/ipod_touch_5.jpg";
            nombre = Camisetas;
        },
                {
            "id_categoria" = 60;
            imagen = "http://exular.es/mcommerce/image/data/ipod_nano_1.jpg";
            nombre = Pantalones;
        }
    );
}
```

It is feed in a dictionary in this piece of code:

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    
    //data =nil;
     NSLog(@"JSNON %@", responseString);   

    NSDictionary *results = [responseString JSONValue];  


    NSLog(@"JSNON %@", results);
```

I need to iterate all the categories in the dictionary and create an NSArray that contains objects Categories with properties "name" and image".

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray *categories = [results objectForKey:@"categoria"];
```

This will create an array of your category objects. You can pass this array of dictionaries/objects to your custom object or just iterate through it pulling what you need.

```
Category *cat = [[Category alloc] initWithDictionary:[categories objectAtIndex:0]];
```

This is just assuming your init is set to handle a dictionary. There isn't enough code to know, but you should be able to figure it out from here.